# Two paragrahps same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Hi i am trying to create kind of a standard email template using html and css. I am finding difficulty fix the footer content that the email address and office address should come in one line.

I am not able to see center email content properly the header needs to fixed header. To see the email content i have added so many break tag

how do i minimize this code using bootstrap or in this code itself.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  text-align: center; 
 }
 
 .navbar {
  position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
  background-color:#3498DB ;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;  
 }
```

```html
<div class="navbar"> 
   <h1><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span></h1>   
  <p> A abcd abcde abcdabcd abc abcde abcdefgh </p>
 </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invitation to join Project ((ProjectName))</h2><br>    
    
    ((InviterFirstName)) ((InviterLastName)) has invited you as ((ProjectRole)) to the following project.<br>
    Project Name: ((ProjectName))<br>
    Project Number: ((ProjectNumber))<br><br><br>

    Team HTML

 <div class="footer">
         <p style="text-align:left;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span><a href="mailto:support@html.com" style="color:white;">support@html.com</a></p> 
  <p style="text-align:right;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span>175B ABC ABCD AB 95138</p> 
  
  
  <p> © 2020 All rights reserved</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put it in a Flexbox. Read more about Flexbox for example [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
* {
font-family: Arial;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  text-align: center; 
 }

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

p {
padding: 10px;
}

img {
padding-right: 5px;
}
 
 .navbar {
  position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
  background-color:#3498DB ;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;  
 }
```

```html
<div class="navbar"> 
   <h1><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span></h1>   
  <p> A abcd abcde abcdabcd abc abcde abcdefgh </p>
 </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Invitation to join Project ((ProjectName))</h2><br>    
    
    ((InviterFirstName)) ((InviterLastName)) has invited you as ((ProjectRole)) to the following project.<br>
    Project Name: ((ProjectName))<br>
    Project Number: ((ProjectNumber))<br><br><br>

    Team HTML

 <div class="footer">

<div class="flex-container">
<p style="text-align:left;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span><a href="mailto:support@html.com" style="color:white;">support@html.com</a></p> 
  <p style="text-align:right;"><span><img width="30" height="30" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Error"></span>175B ABC ABCD AB 95138</p> 
</div>
  
     <p>© 2020 All rights reserved</p>

 </div>
```

Comment: The two lines should come before copy rights reserved line

Comment: Yes but br tags not removed to display center contents properly

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Should I delete the <br> tags?

Comment: Yes after removing br content should be display properly in center

Comment: br tags present on top of h2 tag

Comment: also need to reduce height of header and footer both